# Adding columns of csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I am facing a problem in adding the the data present in two columns of Excel Sheet and get its results.
I tried the below code, but it is concatenating the below columns. Please help

```
file=open( "reads.csv", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        value0=line[0]
        value1=line[1]
        value2= line[0]+line[1]       
        t=value0,value1,value2

        print(t)

('50437171', '150', '50437171150')
('50463638', '107', '50463638107')
('101891833', '150', '101891833150')
('101891682', '151', '101891682151')
('148515110', '150', '148515110150')
('139044904', '119', '139044904119')
('139056020', '151', '139056020151')
('151860851', '103', '151860851103')
('139044904', '151', '139044904151')
('139044905', '150', '139044905150')
('50444197', '151', '50444197151')
```

Comment: What did you expect as output instead? Did you mean to simply print `value2` instead of `t`?

Comment: I want to print value2, which is value0 + value1.

Comment: ***"it is concatenating the below columns"***: I see nothing **concatenated**, doing `t=value0,value1,value2` assings a `tuple` of values to `t`. Read [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple). ***"want to print value2"***: Do `print(value2)`

Comment: I tried Sir. I even tried to typecast the value to integer and then add and even that didnot work. I am new to python. But the problem i am facing is tricky. I printed the initial two values for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

csv.reader reads into strings. You can get around this by using some typecasting:

```
import csv

file   = open("reads.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
    value0 = line[0]
    value1 = line[1]
    value2 = int(line[0]) + int(line[1])
    t      = value0,value1,value2
    print(t)
```

Above, I am assuming that your data is in integer format. If the data is in float format, you would want to use float() instead.

**Suggested improvement**

In general, I would advise using the following instead:

```
import csv

with open("reads.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    column_numbers = [0,1]
    for line in reader:
        t = sum(int(line[i]) for i in column_numbers)
        print(t)
```

This will automatically close the file after the code block has executed, avoiding errors later. The column numbers are also given as an array so that you can swap them out later with ease.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you Sir. It worked. My csv file had a start word written in first column, which was not letting the Typecasting.  Is there some way that reading starts from second row?

Comment: Glad to help. You can start from the second row by using `next(reader)` on the line before `for line in reader:`. This pushes the generator to the next iteration, allowing you to start from the second row.

Answer (score 0):

try the following which casts the strings in the read as integers:

---

```
import csv

f = open("inputdata.csv", "a")
f.write("1,2,3,4,5")
f.write("6,7,8,9,10")
f.write("11,12,13,14,15")

f.close()


file=open( "inputdata.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
    value0=int(line[0])
    value1=int(line[1])
    value2=int(line[0])+int(line[1]) 
    t=value0,value1,value2

    print(t)
```

---

OUTPUT:

---

```
(1, 2, 3)
(6, 7, 13)
(11, 12, 23)
```